# C# skip await operator to allow execution of current method in web API

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have a async method in my Web API service `Do()` and async method `DoAsideStuff()` which is executed inside the first one:

```
public async Task<MyModel> Do(MyRequestModel model){
    //do some important stuff that must be awaited
    await DoImportantStuff();

   //do some aside operations that shouldn't prevent current method execution
    DoAsideStuff(model);

    //do some other important things and return result
    return someResult;
}

private async Task DoAsideStuff(MyRequestModel model)
{
    try{
        //make some http calls, no result needs to be returned
    }
    catch{}
}
```

I would like to allow `Do()` method execution without waiting for the result from inner call `DoAsideStuff()`. It looks like the code above works fine, but I would like to know if there any possible side effects could arise in case of big load on Do() method (like 1000 per sec)?

Comment: Task.WhenAll should let you run both in parallel. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__

Comment: @hazimdikenli WhenAll "represents the completion of all of the supplied tasks" which is not my case

Comment: If you not await the task you never know if it will really complete. The asp.net worker process can terminate and the task will not complete

Comment: @SirRufo Some data loss is allowable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It looks like the code above works fine

This is almost always a bad idea. The main problem is that your app has no idea when that code finishes. In particular, if it finishes *with an exception*, then that exception will be silently swallowed. Also, due to recycling, background work can silently disappear. Also, when the `async` methods resume, they do take threads from the thread pool, and this can interfere with the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics if it's done a lot. Also, if you're on ASP.NET Classic (not Core), then the `async` method may attempt to resume on an ASP.NET request context that has already been disposed/recycled, which can cause some odd errors - you'd want to ensure that `DoAsideStuff` is run *without* a `SynchronizationContext` if you're on ASP.NET Classic.

If those limitations are acceptable, then the only additional side effect when under load is that these are all compounded: you'll have more exceptions silently swallowed, more work silently disappear, and more interference with the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics.